# Passing ASP.net Identity generated Bearer Token to a WCF Restful Service

Tags: web-services, wcf, rest, asp.net-identity

My Scenario:

I have 2 services

Account Service: ASP.NET Web API with Identity Framework that is responsible for individual users to register, login, password reset, change password.. etc.

Order Service: WCF Restful Service that is responsible for Business Logic

What I am trying to do is as follow:

1) Have my mobile client register/login via Account Service to obtain an Individual Account Bearer Token

2) Upon Client send request to Order Service, they will pass this Bearer Token in the Header

My Question is: How can my WCF service validate this Bearer Token? Please feel free to correct my architecture, and or Sample code would be great!

Comment: I would be very much interested if you have found an answer...

Answer (score -1):

I will tell you work around

you will create simple API controller `WCFAuthorizationController` which contains only one simple Action `IsAuthorizedBearerToken(` that will check if this bearer token is valid or not

Then update behavior for wcf service or add any custom configuration 
to call  `/WCFAuthorization/IsAuthorizedBearerToken` before executing operation contract, so

if action `IsAuthorizedBearerToken` return status code `401` (*== not authorized*) you will return not authorized to mobile agent

else you will execute WCF call

I hope this is clear